# Are there some efficient ways to find row(s) meeted conditons which referred to the values in next some rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I wanted to seek efficient ways to find rows meet some conditions in a dataframe. 
The dataframe had n rows and 3 columns. The value were `-1` or `0` or `1`.
I wanted to find the rows which meet two conditions.

1. condition: the value of the row(row0) !=-1;
2. condition: the diagonal of the array generated by the next 3 rows (row1, row2, row3) = 1.

I used loop method to walk all rows and find rows meet the conditions. But, this was not a efficient way especially when there was a big dataframe and the step only was the first step.

```
# Given a dataframe (n*3) 

randNum=random.choices(range(-1,2),k=333) # k=3*int
frame=pd.DataFrame(np.array(randNum).reshape(-1,3))

# its values = -1,0,1, like this:
# In [126]:frame
# Out[126]:
#     0  1  2
# 0    1  0  0
# 1    1 -1  1
# 2    1  1  1
# 3   -1 -1  1
# 4   -1  0 -1
# 5    1  1 -1
# ...
# 105 -1 -1 -1
# 106 -1 -1  0
# 107 -1 -1  0
# 108  0 -1  1
# 109 -1  0  1
# 110  1  0  1
#  I want find the row(s) that all of the values of
#  columns('0','1','2')!=-1, and while the value of 
#  the diagonal of next three rows =1, like this:
#       0  1  2
# row0  v1 v2 v3     # v1!=v2!=v3!=-1, it may be 1 or 0.
# row1   1  v  v
# row2   v  1  v          # v =-1 or 0 or 1
# row3   v  v  1
# the diagonal of rows (row1,row2,row3)=1
```

I want to find the row0 in the DataFrame. It may be resolved by loop        method, but is there exist an efficient solution? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean masks to represent each individual condition. The first is straightforward:

```py
c1_mask = frame[0] != -1

# edited version:
c1_mask = (frame!=-1).all(axis=1)
```

The second one can be solved through a convolution operation

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

c2_mask = convolve2d(frame.values, np.eye(3), mode='valid')
c2_mask = (np.vstack([c2_mask, np.zeros((3, 1))]) == 3).reshape(-1)

# edited version:
c2_kernal = np.vstack((np.zeros((1,3)), np.eye(3)))
c2_mask = convolve2d(frame.values, c2_kernal, mode='valid')
c2_mask = (c2_mask == 3).reshape(-1)
```

Then just combine them:

```py
frame[c1_mask & c2_mask]

# edited version:
(frame[:-3])[(c1_mask[:-3]).shift[-1] & c2_mask]
```

Note that in this solution, the number of  columns is just a parameter, so it can be easily scalable.

Comment: For the record I really like this answer - convolve is a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
randNum=random.choices(range(-1,2),k=333) # k=3*int
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array(randNum).reshape(-1,3))

# `D2` represents the second diagonal (init to -100 to handle last two rows)
# `D3` represents the third diagonal (init to -100 to handle last two rows)
df['D2'] = df['D3'] = -100
df['D2'][0:-1] = df[1][1:]
df['D3'][0:-2] = df[2][2:]
df[(df[0] != -1) & (df[1]!= -1) & (df[2] != -1) & (df[0] + df['D2'] + df['D3'] == 3)]
```

Logic:

1. For any row the second diagonal value will always be in column 1 (D2)
2. For any row the third diagonal value will always be in column 2 (D3)
3. Now it boils down to checking if `[0] + [D2] + [D3] == 3`

Comment: Thanks mujjiga. It did not work. I think the cause may be the slices. The slices of dataframe is with row tag, so D2 can not be assigned in right location. I try to fix it ,but failed. The df.shift may be a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first condition:

```
v1=df[df[0]=!1 & df[1]=!1 & df[2]=!1].index.tolist()
```

second condition:

```
v2=[]
for i in v1:
     if df[0][i+1]==1 and df[1][i+2]==1 and df[1][i+3]==1:
         v2.append(i)
```

to see the indexes of the rows of interest:

```
print(v2)
```

to access the first of these df blocks:

```
df.loc[[v2[0],v2[0]+1,v2[0]+2,v2[0]+3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lotta complicated answers here. I would not do complicated.

```
df.loc[(df != -1).all(axis=1) & (df[0].shift(-1) == 1) & (df[1].shift(-2) == 1) & (df[2].shift(-3) == 1), :]
```

Comment: This isn't correct boolean indexing, did you try to run this code? You'll get a `TypeError`

Comment: No. I answered this on my phone. I added the perens to fix it.

Comment: thanks CJR. I had fixed it. like this: df.loc[((df != -1).all(axis=1) )& (df[0].shift(-1) == 1) & (df[1].shift(-2) == 1) & (df[2].shift(-3) == 1), :]